# Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Tags: geometry

For a point $P = (x, y)$ in the plane, write $f(P) = ax+by$, where $a$ and $b$
are given real numbers. Let $f(A) = f(B) = 10$. Let $C$ be a point not on the
line joining $A$ and $B$ and let $C_0$ be the reflection of $C$ with respect to this
line. If $f(C) = 15$, find $f(C_0)$

Comment: OK, what part of the problem do you not understand?

Comment: I can't think of a single question on this site that that title distinguishes your question from.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The hypotheses tell us that $A$ and $B$ are on the line $\ell$ whose equation is $ax+by=10$. Let $C=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$; we’re also told that $ax_0+by_0=15$.

1. The lines $ax+by=c$ for different values of $c$ are all parallel. Show that for any $c$ and $d$, the perpendicular distance between the lines $ax+by=c-d$ and $ax+by=c$ is the same as the perpendicular distance between the lines $ax+by=c$ and $ax+by=c+d$.
2. Conclude that $C_0$ must lie on the line $ax+by=5$.
3. $C_0$ must also lie on the line through $C$ perpendicular to $\ell$, so to find $C_0$, you need only find the equation of this line and solve for its point of intersection with the line $ax+by=5$.

It may help to take care of one special case first, if only to get a clearer picture of what’s going on.

If $b=0$, then the line $\ell$ through $A$ and $B$ is the vertical line $x=\frac{10}a$. $C$ is not on this line, so $x_0\ne\frac{10}a$. Let $d=x_0-\frac{10}a$; then $C$ is $d$ units to the right of $\ell$. (If $d$ is negative, $C$ is $|d|$ units to the left of $\ell$.) Its mirror image in $\ell$ must be the point $d$ units to the left of $\ell$ and at the same height (i.e., with the same $y$-coordinate); that point is $\left\langle\frac{10}a-d,y_0\right\rangle=\left\langle\frac{20}a-x_0,y_0\right\rangle$.

Now consider the case $b\ne 0$. The line $\ell$ through $A$ and $B$ has the equation $y=\frac{10}b-\frac{a}bx$ and hence has slope $-\frac{a}b$. The line through $C$ and its reflection $C_0$ must be perpendicular to $\ell$, so its slope must be $\frac{b}a$. This will be needed to carry out (3) above.

Comment: Hi Brian -- perhaps I'm missing something, or perhaps you're trying to give lots of details to be helpful; but it seems to me you're burying a simple connection in a lot of details. Pairs of lines of constant $f$ that are at the same distance from each other differ by the same amount in $f$; since $C$ and $C_0$ are at the same distance from the line joining $A$ and $B$ but on opposite sides, we must have $f(C_0)=5$, no?

Comment: @joriki: Isn’t that what I said in (1) and (2)? And I suspect that the general fact in (1), which is what you’re using, is neither obvious nor trivial to verify for most students at the level at which they’re likely to encounter this problem $-$ at least if they have to ask about the problem.

Comment: I defer to your better pedagogical judgement, since I've never taught this sort of thing; I would have thought that treating this on a coordinate level with special cases for vertical lines obscures the bigger picture, but perhaps that's only the case if one can already see the bigger picture clearly...